# PHP routing is not working, getting page not found

Tags: php, routes

Under `htdocs` folder i have created folder called `PHP` under that i have created file called `index.php`. I have written wrouting PHP code but it is not working.

> index.php

```
<?php
echo "Welcome" . "<br>";
$routes = [];

route('/', function () {
  echo "Home Page";
});

route('/login', function () {
  echo "Login Page";
});

route('/about-us', function () {
  echo "About Us";
});

route('/404', function () {
  echo "Page not found";
});

function route(string $path, callable $callback) {
  global $routes;
  $routes[$path] = $callback;
}

run();

function run() {
  global $routes;
  $uri = $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'];
  $found = false;
  foreach ($routes as $path => $callback) {
    if ($path !== $uri) continue;

    $found = true;
    $callback();
  }

  if (!$found) {
    $notFoundCallback = $routes['/404'];
    $notFoundCallback();
  }
}
```

> http://localhost/PHP/

```
Welcome
Page not found
```

> http://localhost/PHP/index.php/login/   (getting below output)

```
Welcome
Page not found
```

> Expected output

```
Welcome
Login Page
```

Here wt am doing mistake, can anyone explain and update my code

Comment: should it be `localhost/login`?

Comment: which web server you are using? apache?

Comment: @Giacomo M, I am using apache

Comment: @nhy, how it will work, under PHP folder index.php file was there

Comment: Have you done any debugging, like checking what `$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']` actually contains?